# ios - Why is Flipside controller so complicated?

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

Just a quick question.

I am busy with an iPhone app based on the Utility Application template to set me up with the Core Data info.

I was just wondering, why the FlipViewController is set up the way that it is.

Is it not much easier to do link in storyboard with a modalview segue a

```
- (IBAction)doneFlip:(id)sender
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To return to the previous view?

Is this a performance reason?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's templates are always a mess in Xcode 4.x.  For those who can remember way back to Xcode 2.x or even early 3.x, the templates were relatively uniform with excellent comments and very little extra gruff in the way.  But in 4.x, the templates have become a jarring mix of coding styles, preferences, and traditions from Apple's many Xcode developers.

As for that:

```
- (IBAction)doneFlip:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

`-dismissModalViewController` would not be the best thing to use (it should be called from the presenting controller.  Use `-popViewControllerAnimated` instead if it is in an action from inside the presented view.

Comment: No, you're sane.  It's those Xcode devs who work so hard on the application, that they neglect the content.